# IntentService Terminated before Picasso loads Bitmap

Tags: android, picasso, intentservice

I'm trying to use an IntentService for processing and uploading images that's running in a different process to have more memory. I'm Using also Picasso to load the Image. When the Image is small the bitmap is loaded successfully and uploaded, however if the image is big the IntentService is terminated before Picasso is done loading It.

Picasso have to run on UIThread

Here is the code.

```
private void downloadImage(File file) {
    final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Picasso.with(NewImageProcessingService.this).load(uri).transform(new ImageLoadingUtil.DecreaseQualityTransformation(imageQuality)).into(NewImageProcessingService.this);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    File file = (File) intent.getSerializableExtra(KEY_IMAGE_FILE);
    imageQuality = ImagesUtils.IMAGE_QUALITY
            .values()[intent.getIntExtra(IMAGE_QUALITY, ImagesUtils.IMAGE_QUALITY.DEFAULT.ordinal())];
    downloadImage(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but if anyone steps by. The `Target` is getting garbage collected before it can show the bitmap.

Use it like this

```
public class BitmapLoader {

public static Target getViewTarget(final OnImageLoadingCompleted onCompleted) {
    return new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            onCompleted.imageLoadingCompleted(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };
}
}
```

You need to have a strong reference to the `Target` so have a field in your `IntentService` holding it e.g.

```
private Target viewTarget;

viewTarget = BitmapLoader.getViewTarget(bitmap -> {
           // do stuff with the bitmap
        });
 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(object.getImageUrl()).into(viewTarget));
```